# How to configure Mattermost Plugins

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, mattermost

I have deployed Mattermost Team Edition from the [Helm Chart](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-helm/tree/master/charts/mattermost-team-edition)
onto my k8s Cluster and it's working great.
The issue is that the `config.json` file is mounted as a secret, 
so configuration can't be done from the UI but in the config.json that is part of values.yaml in the helm chart.
How does one configure plugins? For starters, I would like to enable the zoom plugin

```
configJSON: {
  "PluginSettings": {
    "Enable": true,
    "EnableUploads": true,
    "Directory": "./plugins",
    "ClientDirectory": "./client/plugins",
    "Plugins": {},
    "PluginStates": {
       "zoom": {
         "Enable": true
       },
       "com.mattermost.nps": {
         "Enable": false
       },
       "mattermost-webrtc-video": {
         "Enable": true
       },
       "github": {
         "Enable": true
       },
       "jira": {
         "Enable": true
       },
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of enabling the plugins? 
How do I configure the plugins,
especially the *zoom* one needs API credentials..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

### The safe way

Run another Mattermost server instance locally (for exemple using the [Mattermost preview Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/mattermost/mattermost-preview/), very easy to set up), configure your plugins and use its configuration file section for your cluster instances.

### The manual, error-prone way

Edit the config.json yourself as you've started. For each plugin, there are two sections to edit, `Plugins` and `PluginStates`:

```
"PluginSettings": {
        // [...]
        "Plugins": {
            "your.plugin.id": {
                "pluginProperty1": "...",
                "pluginProperty2": "...", 
                "pluginProperty3": "...",
                // [...]
            },
        },
        "PluginStates": {
            // [...]
            "your.plugin.id": {
                "Enable": true
            },
        }
    }
```

As you see, this requires to know what properties are defined for each plugin, for  which there's only the solution to consult the plugin's documentation, or even it's code (look for a file called `plugin.json` at the root of the plugin's GitHub repo, in the `settings` section).

I would recommand the first method if there's really no way for you to use the GUI to install&configure plugins.

For other readers' information, **in most Mattermost setups, you *should* be able to use the UI for this**, even in [High Availability Mode](https://docs.mattermost.com/administration/plugins.html#plugin-uploads-in-high-availability-mode) if your version is recent enough.

Comment: I like the local MM instance with a docker container idea. I upgraded the version to 5.22, and I'll check if it now allows settings in the GUI even with my current helm deployment.

Comment: Good luck with that! Beware, High availabilty Cluster mode is not available in the Team Edition though, so that might not be applicable to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your values.yaml:

```
config:
  MM_PLUGINSETTINGS_CLIENTDIRECTORY: "./client/plugins"
  MM_PLUGINSETTINGS_ENABLEUPLOADS: "true"
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.